# how do I reduce number of for loops?

Tags: arrays, swift, logic, boolean-logic

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 4]
let sumOf = 8 

func sumOfArrayFuntion(_ array: [Int], sumOf: Int) -> Bool {
    var isTrue = false
    
    for i in 0...array.count-1 {
        for j in 0...array.count-1 {
            for k in 0...array.count-1 {
                if array[i] + array[j] + array[k] == sumOf {
                    isTrue = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return isTrue
}

sumOfArrayFuntion(array, sumOf: sumOf)
```

> function returns true if any three integers in an array add to sumOf variable, this code is not efficient, more importantly how do I think if being efficient.

Comment: Homework assignment, online challenge? Any restrictions in how this can be solved you haven’t mentioned? Also, have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: this was my interview question, my solution if the one I wrote but interviewer wanted me to improve the code..

Comment: Ok I understand. So no restrictions then and the text at the bottom was the feedback.

Comment: yes that was the feedback..

Comment: One quick improvement is to replace `isTrue = true` with `return true` so you don’t continue looping after you have found a match.

Comment: thanks, any idea on the for loops or any other way you would solve this?

Comment: Three for loops is fine. You just need to 1) avoid selecting the same element multiple times, 2) avoid checking the same triplet more than once, 3) return immediately upon finding a solution.  @HangarRash’s solution solves these three issues.

Answer (score 2):

Don’t start each loop at zero. You are wasting a lot of time checking invalid combinations. Also stop each loop at the appropriate point. And you can return as soon as you find a match.

I’ve also updated the code to cut down on the number of additions.

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 4]
let sumOf = 8 

func sumOfArrayFuntion(_ array: [Int], sumOf: Int) -> Bool {
    guard array.count >= 3 else { return false }

    for i in 0..<array.count-2 {
        for j in i+1..<array.count-1 {
            let sum = array[i] + array[j]
            for k in j+1..<array.count {
                if sum + array[k] == sumOf {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

sumOfArrayFuntion(array, sumOf: sumOf)
```

Comment: This is a correct, efficient solution. It checks all possible triplets, avoids selecting the same element twice, and avoids multiple checks of the same triplet since i<j<k at all times.

Comment: You can reduce the number of addition operations by storing the i + j partial result. Do some timings with large arrays to see if this results in a faster solution.

Comment: Also remove all numbers that higher or equal than ```sumOf-1``` if array not include 0. If include, just higher than ```sumOf```

Comment: @vacawama Just updated to include the addition optimization.

Comment: @CosmicTea You should be able to remove all values great than or equal to `sumOf-2` if all values are 1 or higher.

Comment: Your optimization is adding multiple `array[j]` to `sum`.  You should just do `let sum = array[i] + array[j]`.  Or even better: `let target = sumOf - array[i] - array[j]`, then `if array[k] == target { return true }`

Comment: @vacawama Oops. Fixed. The trouble with typing an answer on the phone and no computer to verify it on.